# disable swiping tabs in TabBar flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I have a tab bar in Flutter and I want to disable swiping between tabs

```
      // Set the bottom navigation bar
      bottomNavigationBar: new Material(

        // set the color of the bottom navigation bar
        color: const Color(0xFFF7F7F7),
        // set the tab bar as the child of bottom navigation bar
        child: new TabBar(
          tabs: <Tab>[
            new Tab(
              // set icon to the tab
              icon: new Icon(Icons.home,color: Colors.black),
            ),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite,color: Colors.black),
            ),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.black),
            ),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.settings,color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
          // setup the controller
          controller: controller,


        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am moving tabs on clicking each tab bar button and I want to disable swiping thank you

Comment: if i understand you correctly  you are trying to disable the indicator because i don't understand what do you mean by "swiping" in TabBar

Comment: By swipe: i mean you you can move from tab to another by swiping left or right

Comment: take a look at my answer

Comment: Ok thank you well done!

Answer (score 265, accepted):

you can achieve that by changing how the page view should respond to user input using the `physics` property. and we have a `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` for that purpose so just change `physics` to that like this :

```
TabBarView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: tabcontroler,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(color: Colors.red),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
          Container(color: Colors.blue),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 25):

### **physics**: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

**1.** You can disable swiping from **TabBarView()**

```
TabBarView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: tabcontroler,
        children: <Widget>[]
)
```

**2.** You can disable scrooling from **ListView()** , **PageView()**

```
 ListView.builder(
    // you can set BouncingScrollPhysics() if you show animation when user end of list
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: categories.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
            return CategoryItem(categories[index]);
          },
)


PageView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
)
```

---

physics accept these value :  
1. **BouncingScrollPhysics()** : bouncing scrolling when you end/start of list
2. **NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()** : stop tab change OR stop list scrolling OR stop page change of pageview
3. **ClampingScrollPhysics()**  : normal behaviour

Comment: Worth noting that "BouncingScrollPhysics" is the default for Cupertino widgets, while "ClampingScrollPhysics" is the default for Material widgets

Answer (score 3):

Use **physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),** in TabBarView

```
TabBarView(
   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), <---- Add line
   children: [
      child1(),
      child2(),
   ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the physics to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()

```
TabBarView(
   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   children: [
     EditorPickTabView(),
     AllProfileTabView(),
   ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

in Tabbar or ListView or PageView