# How to disable swiping left or right in Dismissible widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to disable swiping to the right once there are no data in DataBase.

```dart
if (data.length > 1) {
  // I can swipe to the left or right
} else {
  // I can't swipe to the right only left
}
```

Is it real to achieve this?
Perhaps, I can return an element to the center once one swiped it to the right

**Solution**:
I just used confirmDismiss in Dismissible widget.

```
confirmDismiss: (direction) {
  if(data.length > 0 && direction==..)
  // do stuff
  else if(...)
}
```

Answer (score 20):

A late answer but you can set the `direction` property of `Dismissible` as `direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,` or `direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,`

Answer (score 16):

Although Sergio's solution works when you have a simple scenario, in my case I had a complex tree below the Dismissible widget (which needed to accept other types of interactions).

Peeking @ [flutter's source for Dismissible](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c6fe7bb9e13dc630d04a0553ae74c9bdfd913688/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/dismissible.dart), I noticed we can set the property `direction` to `DismissDirection.none` to prevent swipes.  e.g.:

```dart
Dismissible(
   key: UniqueKey(),
   direction: !_canSwipe ? DismissDirection.none : DismissDirection.horizontal,
   (...)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: replace `null` with `DismissDirection.none`

Answer (score 14):

You can use direction property

Set it to `DismissDirection.endToStart` or `DismissDirection.startToEnd`

```
Dismissible(
    direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
    )
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Other options will also give the same result but why over-code if there is a property for that.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone wants to disable dismiss swiping altogether (left or right) you can use DismissDirection.none

*Note this parameter is currently only available on the beta channel

```
Dismissible(
  direction: data.length > 1 ? DismissDirection.endToStart : DismissDirection.none,
)
```

Answer (score 8):

Wrap the dismissible widget with `AbsorbPointer`. Then, whenever you don't want item to be dismissed, set `absorbing` to true. Check this for more info [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html)

Comment: Although AbsorbPointer would prevent swiping, it would also prevent clicking and interacting with the element within the Dismissable, which may include buttons and checkbox (in my case). Solution from @tomblue is most accurate..

Answer (score 2):

Following tomblue's idea I came up with another idea which not only comes free of any error (both compilation and runtime) but also allows the developer to prevent swipe to the right or to the left:

I used the ternary with the properties in dismissThresholds set to impossible values. Full example below:

```dart
class SwiperState extends State<Swiper> {
    bool _isNotFirstIndex = false;
    bool _isNotLastIndex = true;
    int _currentIndex = 0;

    void nextOne() {
        setState(() {
            _isNotFirstIndex = !(_currentIndex - 1 < 0);
            _isNotLastIndex = !(_currentIndex + 1 == count);
        });
    }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
        dismissThresholds:  {DismissDirection.startToEnd: _isNotFirstIndex ? 0.05 : 2.00, 
            DismissDirection.endToStart: _isNotLastIndex ? 0.05 : 2.00},
        key: UniqueKey(),
        onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
          if(direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
            // dismissed to the left, next one
            nextOne();
          }
          else (do the same with prevOne())
               (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

These links might be helpful:

[disable swiping tabs in TabBar flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518393/disable-swiping-tabs-in-tabbar-flutter/51523272)

https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-disable-swiping-tabs-in-flutter-tabbar/

Answer (score 0):

Set the `direction` property to `DismissDirection.none`.

Example:

```dart
Dismissible(
    direction: isEnabled
        ? DismissDirection.endToStart
        : DismissDirection.none,
    child: // Rest of code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a newly proposed api change, and until then unfortunately we have to reuse the code.

```
return isDisabled ?
      CardWidgetAndCode(
        ...
      )
    : Dismissible(
      child: CardWidgetAndCode( //  <-- duplicate code and/or function call
        ...
      )
    )
```