# How to block scrolling to left from current page?

Tags: flutter

I have TabBarView that has 4 tab(page). I wanna block scrolling to left from current page but I couldn't do that. If you need more information than below codes, please you say me.

```
`TabBarView shationTabBarView({required TabController tabController}) => TabBarView(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: tabController,
      children: const [
        DashboardView(),
        ChatView(),
        AdvertView(),
        ProfileView(),
      ],
    );

TabBar shationTabView({required TabController tabController}) => TabBar(
      onTap: (index) {},
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      controller: tabController,
      indicatorColor: ProjectColorsUtility.projectBackgroundWhite,
      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
      labelColor: ProjectColorsUtility.eveningStar,
      unselectedLabelColor: ProjectColorsUtility.onboardBlack,
      tabs: TabViews.values
          .map((e) => Tab(
                icon: IconOfTabs.items[e.index],
              ))
          .toList(),
    );`
```

I used NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() but it didn't work and after I scrolled to left from current page on the app, empty page that has CircularProgressIndicator.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to allow swipe to right but block from swiping to left. If you want to block from all swiping, you can checkout this reference: [disable swiping tabs in TabBar flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518393/disable-swiping-tabs-in-tabbar-flutter). If I understand right, you can use this:

```
class MyTabScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyTabScreenState createState() => _MyTabScreenState();
}

class _MyTabScreenState extends State<MyTabScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  late PageController _pageController;
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _currentIndex);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleTabSelection() {
    if (_currentIndex != _tabController.index) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = _tabController.index;
        _pageController.jumpToPage(_currentIndex);
      });
    }
  }

  void _navigateToPage(int index) {
    if (index > _currentIndex) {
      _pageController.animateToPage(
        index,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tab Bar'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            onTap: (index) => _navigateToPage(index),
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: const [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard, color: Colors.black)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.chat, color: Colors.black)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.abc, color: Colors.black)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.black)),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
              onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
                  // Swiping to the left
                  _navigateToPage(_currentIndex + 1);
                }
              },
              child: PageView(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                controller: _pageController,
                onPageChanged: (index) => _tabController.animateTo(index),
                children: const [
                  Center(child: Text("1")),
                  Center(child: Text("2")),
                  Center(child: Text("3")),
                  Center(child: Text("4")),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can edit your scrolling animation as Flutter's document: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves-class.html

Comment: it didin't work,